# Unsure of how to unit test password validation function that uses bCrypt.compare(), getting undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

I am trying to write a jest unit test for my validateUser function, but when I call the function in my test I am always getting the value `undefined` returned.

**additional context**

- I am using nestJS as my api framework, I have mocked my user findOne query function to return `expectedUserObjHashed`.
- I am using [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) to handle hashing and comparing passwords, I am using `hashSync` and `compare` from the library in this test
- (not sure if this was the proper way to validate) but I added log statements to verify that my test is making it into the `if(result)` block and not throwing an exception.

I am guessing this is some async problem but I've been trying to a few hours a day for a couple days and im not sure where its occuring.

```js
// This is the set up for my test
  const saltRounds = 10;
  let hashedPassword: string;
  let expectedUserObjHashed: any;

  beforeAll(() => {
    hashedPassword = hashSync('test123!', saltRounds);
    expectedUserObjHashed = {
      id: 1,
      email: 'test@test.com',
      first_name: 'foo',
      last_name: 'barr',
      password: hashedPassword,
    };
  });
```

```js
it('should validate password', async () => {
    expect(
      await service.validateUser(
// expectedUserObjUnhashed is a duplicate of expectedUserObjHashed minus having the password property hashed
        expectedUserObjUnhashed.email,
        expectedUserObjUnhashed.password,
      ),
// validatedUserObj is the same as the other UserObj objects but the password property is removed
    ).toStrictEqual(validatedUserObj);
  });
```

```js
async validateUser(email: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
// findUserByEmail() is mocked in the test to return expectedUserObjHashed (noted above before code blocks)
    const user = await this.userService.findUserByEmail(email);
    if (user !== undefined) {
     compare(password, user.password, function (err, result) {
        if (result) {
          const { password, ...userInfo } = user;
          console.log(userInfo);
          return userInfo;
        } else {
          throw new UnauthorizedException();
        }
      });
    } else {
      throw new BadRequestException();
    }
  }
```

**Update:** I wrote a controller to test the `validateUser()` function in postman and it seems that it is not getting any return value (which is probably why the test got `undefined`) but right in the `bcrypt.compare()` callback (right before the `return userInfo` line) I logged `userInfo` and it is defined, so now i'm unsure why the callback is not returning `userInfo` as instructed.

**Update 2:**
I played around with my implementation of `bcrypt.compare()` and I got it to work like this:

```js
...
const isMatch = await compare(password, user.password);
      if (isMatch) {
        const { password, ...userInfo } = user;
        return userInfo;
      } else {
        throw new UnauthorizedException();
      }
...
```

I would still like to know why my original implementation did not work for my knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
compare(password, user.password, function (err, result) {
 if (result) {
  const { password, ...userInfo } = user;
  console.log(userInfo);
  return userInfo;
 } else {
  throw new UnauthorizedException();
 }
```

Function inside compare is a callback that works after compare is done. So compare is firing and it returns nothing and if it's done that function is running so console.log it's working but return don't have any effect. When you added await you actually waited for compare to be complete.